# Get counts of products according to parent category

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I want count of the products according to category and my category level is of nth level 
I had tried below query but I am not getting result as expected:

```
SELECT count(p.prod_id),c.cat_name_eng,c.cat_id FROM product p 
left join category c on c.cat_id = p.cat_id group by p.cat_id
```

Sample Data:


**category_table:**

```
cat_id   name    parent_id
1       craft       0
2       company     0
3       test        1   
4       test1       3       
5       test2       2   
6       test3       4
7       test4       5
```

**product_table:**

```
prod_id     cat_id  
1           1   
2           6
3           6   
4           4
5           2
6           7
```

Expected Output:

```
+----------+------------------------+
| Category | Count in Product Table |
+----------+------------------------+
| craft    |                      4 |
| company  |                      2 |
+----------+------------------------+
```

I dont want count of test, test1, test2, test3 and test4 because

1. test has parent_id = 1, i.e. craft
2. test1 has parent_id = 3, i.e. test which in turn has parent_id = 1,
   i.e. craft
3. test3 has parent_id = 4, i.e. test1 which in has parent_id = 3, i.e. test
   which in turn has parent_id = 1, i.e. craft
4. test2 has parent_id = 2, i.e. company
5. test4 has parent_id = 5, i.e. test2 which in turn has parent_id = 2, i.e. company

So count for test, test1 and test3 will go to Count of craft category.

and count for test2 and test4 will go to Count of company category.

Comment: Add php code you have done yet.

Comment: If you have only two sublevel you could build a sql  .. if you have dinamic sublevel ... then mysql have not Features to manage hierarchical structures .. so you shold work witha server side procedural languege and iteration on sublevel

Comment: What is the output of your tried query ?

Comment: not getting as expected

Comment: Ideal solution is to have a recursive function that will get the cat_ids from a category and then count the number of products in this cat_ids.

Comment: Try this select count(*),cat_id from products where cat_id in (select cat_id from category) group by cat_id